# Keep tibbles as tibbles after reshape2::dcast

Tags: r, tidyverse, reshape2, tibble, dcast

Is there a way to get `dcast` to output a tibble? (without using `as_tibble`)

```
df <- tibble(a = letters[c(rep(1:3, 3), 1)], b =  1:10 + .1, c = 11:20 + .1)

df %>% class
# [1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
df %>% dcast(a ~ b) %>% class
# [1] "data.frame"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `reshape2` package has been retired and will unlikely be updated to support tibbles. If you want to stick with tibbles, you should use the tidyverse version of the `reshape2` package which is called `tidyr`. You can use

```
library(tidyr)
df %>% spread(b, c)
```

Comment: Just note that `spread` will work for simple cases like `dcast(a ~ b)`, but doesn't handle complex cases like `dcast(a + b ~ c + d)`.  (at least not that I'm aware). There's talk of adding this to `tidyr` somewhere (can't find a link).